# upload an image into mysql database using windows universal app

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xaml, win-universal-app

i've been trying to insert an image from my phone into mysql database using a windows universal app and 2 php files . 
here is my xaml code `

```
    <TextBox x:Name="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="nameB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="2" Width="174"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="UserMail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="emailB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="2" Width="174"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="UserImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,218,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="imageB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="2" Width="119"/>
    <PasswordBox  x:Name="UserPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,145,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="2" Width="141"/>

    <Button x:Name="UploadImage" Content="upload" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,218,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="upload_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="SubmitUser" Content="submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,297,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="submit_Click"/>
</Grid>`
```

and here is my mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            UserImage.Text =  file.Name;
        }

    }

    private async void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* NameValueCollection UserInfo = new NameValueCollection();
         UserInfo.Add("UserName", UserName.Text);
         UserInfo.Add("UserMail", UserMail.Text);

         UserInfo.Add("UserPassword", UserPassword.Password);
         UserInfo.Add("UserImage", UserImage.Text);
         */
        ///*********/////




        String url = "http://172.19.241.135/tutorial/insertStudent.php";
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName",UserName.Text),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserMail",UserMail.Text),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserPassword",UserPassword.Password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserImage",UserImage.Text)

        };


        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("added succesfully ");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // problems handling here
                string msg = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();

                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            // .. and understanding the error here
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
        }



    }
}
```

and i'm stuck now as i was trying to use a windows phone code , but i can't find a replacement for

`byte[] insertuser= client.uploadValues("",values);
client.Headers.Add("content_type","binary/octet_stream");
byte[] insertUserImage=client.uploadFile("",FileChooser.FileName) ;`

it seems that these methods are no more available in windows universal apps
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For UWP app, if you want to upload an image, you will need to convert this image to stream, and use this stream as the content of [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.aspx).

There is an official [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/17b1dbd0985d3241582381fb50608e0449cc2537/Samples/HttpClient/cs/HttpClient), scenario 5 in this sample is about using HTTP POST command to upload a stream to a server.

The code for server is also included in this sample, you can see how to resolve the uploaded stream for the server.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm actually lost , so could you  give me  a little more details . In fact i want to add a new product into mydatabse from my app and then display those products in  my **UWP** application . So i need to choose a picture (i think using filepicker) and prepare my **php** file to upload the image in **Mysql**.

Comment: Yes, you can use `filepicker` to choose a select a picture from your app, but the chosen picture is actually a `StorageFile`, you can convert this `StorageFile` to stream by `IRandomAccessStream imgstream = await file.OpenReadAsync();`, and you can upload this stream.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help ... i tried to do as you already mentioned .. but i'm stuck .. can you please give me full example ...