# how to use httpClient.postAsync to upload an image or bytes[] in UWP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, image, win-universal-app

so i need to upload an image into my Mysql databse along with some other strings like name for an example ...
i was able to add the name into Mysql DB but i can not do it for the image .
I converted the image inti an byte [] and i'm stuck now .. 
here is the code i used

```
private Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open a stream for the selected file
        StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // Ensure a file was selected
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                fileStream.AsStream().CopyTo(stream);
                img.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/mydatabase/add.php");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        request.Content = streamContent;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, streamContent).AsTask(cts.Token);



    }
```

Comment: that's the updated code i'm using ... but it's not working ... i keep getting Azure errors

Comment: @It's impolite that you copy the code in the answer for editing your question to another, you can accept the answer below and ask a new question. It's unfair to Grace. We are not here to write all code for you.

Comment: sorry i know but i'm  stuck  here ... thank you .. i promise i won't bother you again once i find a  solution

Comment: i think this guid will help you http://kiewic.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpStreamContent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpstreamcontent.aspx) to upload stream directly to your web server. For example:

```
private Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void SelectImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
    open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

    // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
    open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
    open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

    // Open a stream for the selected file
    StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

    // Ensure a file was selected
    if (file != null)
    {
        // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            fileStream.AsStream().CopyTo(stream);
            img.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}

private async void UploadImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("you web uri");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
    request.Content = streamContent;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, streamContent).AsTask(cts.Token);
}
```

As we've discussed in your another question, you may refer to the official [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient), scenario 5 is about posting stream.

For a client app, what we can do is just uploading the file stream correctly, and the important thing is, **you will need to implement the image decoding function and save to mysql in your server.**

By the way, you've asked the same question [upload an image into mysql database using windows universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543367/upload-an-image-into-mysql-database-using-windows-universal-app/35567734#comment59549239_35567734) once and I've seen your newest comment to my answer, I won't update my answer in that case, hope this is the right you asked for.

Comment: Thanks ,i really appreciate your help ... but , the problem i'm facing now is that i'm trying to use a php file to upload the to Mysql Db but i keep getting errors related to Azure .. you'll find the updated code .. please check it above

Comment: @hilaryduff, So, now it's have no business with UWP any more, and it's not my scope any more. But my answer is not wrong for an UWP app, would you please mark it and ask a new question without any "win-universal-app" tag. I'm sure someone else will help you.

Comment: @ Grace Feng thank you, i really do apppreciate your help .. but actually my problem is still UWP as i'm trying to uoplad an image via UWP bu i keep getting... please check the image i aded above ... i promise i won't bother you again but i'm reallu stuck and have deadline .. thanks again

Comment: As I said, my code is for UWP app to upload a selected picture from your local machine, this is done in the client app. You should have no problem in UWP app upload image. The left problem is no related to UWP app, it's your server, your php code, your database, **is implementation the image decoding function and save to mysql in your server**. It's not be done in the UWP or client app, it's all your server, understand? And I'm not able to write a server code, so, please ask a new question, for example: how to use php+mysql to decode the image stream and store the stream to database.

Comment: ok ... thank you and sorry for bothering you ..one last thing to ask please , i downloaded the "Windows-universal-samples-master" and i extracted the whole folder .. but unfornately i can not run httpClient sample and the whenever i click manage NugetPackage i get this "**  Could not install package 'Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.** "... so could you please  help me solve this issue

Comment: @hilaryduff, and it could never be bothering for asking a question, on the contrary, it's good to ask question, to keep thinking. But php+mysql for a web server is really not my skill, and it's not related to UWP. Did you try to run other samples? HttpClient sample include a server in its folder, you will need to deploy this server at first. Read the "Read me" doc of the sample please.

Comment: Thank you .. PS: i marked your answer as a correct one ...Thank you Sir again ... you've been a great help for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this its working for me:

```
private static async Task Upload(string actionUrl)
{
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"Absolute Path of image");
    ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] paramFileStream= (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(newImage, typeof(byte[]));

    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        //send form text values here
        {new StringContent("value1"), "key1"},
        {new StringContent("value2"), "key2" },
        // send Image Here
        {new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(paramFileStream)), "imagekey", "filename.jpg"}
    };

    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(actionUrl.ToString(), formContent);
    string stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return response;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I don't know what's missing but I keep getting `StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'`

Comment: @djack109 : Did you able to resolve this  StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'  issue  ?

Answer (score 1):

@semwal

I can't recall specifically what was the actual fix but here is my solution. Hope it helps

```
   public async Task<JsonApiResult> SendHttpData(string file, string token, string claimid, string serviceMethod)
    {
        serviceMethod = $"{serviceMethod}/?claimid={claimid}&token={token}";

        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);

        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(file));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "result", FileName = $"\"{filename}\"" };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

            content.Add(fileContent);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(serviceMethod, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new JsonApiResult { Result = "success", Message = "File Sent", Data = "" };
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonApiResult { Result = "fail", Message = response.ToString(), Data = "" };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new JsonApiResult { Result = "fail", Message = e.Message, Data = "" };
        }
    }
}
```